# Failure to create unique button icons with for loop Java

Tags: java, button, for-loop, icons

I have created an SSCCE that mimics the issue I am having with my code. Essentially I am trying to create a series of buttons each displaying the same image but with a different color. For whatever reason, all the buttons end up the same color at the end, and it's always the last color I used.

Here is the code:

```
package buttonFail;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends Canvas{

    public static Color[] COLORS = {Color.red, Color.blue};

    Main() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(32, 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillOval(8, 8, 14, 14);


        for (int i = 0; i < COLORS.length; i++) {
            BufferedImage buffer = img;
            for (int y = 0; y < buffer.getHeight(); y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < buffer.getWidth(); x++) {
                    if ((buffer.getRGB(x, y) & 0x00FFFFFF) != 0x00000000) {
                        buffer.setRGB(x, y, COLORS[i].getRGB());
                    }
                }
            }
            panel.add(new JButton(new ImageIcon(buffer)));
        }

        frame.add(this);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        panel.setFocusable(true);
        panel.requestFocusInWindow();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't share one `buffer-image` .create individual `BufferImage` for each button.you create a red buffer image first and add it to button 1.and then you change buffer image to blue .since both buttons share same buffer image previous button1 image icon color also get changed to blue.

try that.each button has it's own buffer image.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < COLORS.length; i++) {

            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(32, 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            BufferedImage buffer = img;
            Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillOval(8, 8, 14, 14);

            for (int y = 0; y < buffer.getHeight(); y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < buffer.getWidth(); x++) {
                    if ((buffer.getRGB(x, y) & 0xFF000000) == 0xFF000000) {
                        buffer.setRGB(x, y, COLORS[i].getRGB());
                    }
                }
            }
            panel.add(new JButton(new ImageIcon(buffer)));
        }
```

output>>

[image]

Comment: YES! I got this to work on my actual code by manually reloading the BufferedImage from file inside the loop. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Seem like the reference of the Image object is same.  Here is my modified code.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

for (int i = 0; i < COLORS.length; i++) {
    BufferedImage buffer = new BufferedImage(32, 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = buffer.createGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillOval(8, 8, 14, 14);
    for (int y = 0; y < buffer.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < buffer.getWidth(); x++) {
            if ((buffer.getRGB(x, y) & 0xFF000000) == 0xFF000000) {
                buffer.setRGB(x, y, COLORS[i].getRGB());
            }
        }
    }
    panel.add(new JButton(new ImageIcon(buffer)));
}

frame.add(this);
frame.add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
panel.setFocusable(true);
panel.requestFocusInWindow();
```